# Is this a partially applied function?

Tags: scala

Recently I've found a code snippet:

```
case t @ MethCall(o,m) => ((t -> input)(o)) match {
  case Some(o @ ObjType(_,_)) => o.retType(m)
  case _ => None
}
```

I was interested in the next expression:

```
(t -> input)(o)
```

I know that `(t -> input)` is a `Tuple2`. But what does mean invocation `(o)`? I didn't find such factory method in `Tuple2`. So what does `(t -> input)(o)` mean in the code snippet?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what `MethCall` actually is. If it has a method `->`, then `(t -> input)` isn't necessarily a `Tuple2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy to guess what `->` means in this context. It does not have to be a `->` defined in Scala Predef/ArrowAssoc. Here are couple alternatives:

1) It can defined as a method on `MethCall` class:

```
case class MethCall(v: Int) { def ->(in: String)(other: String) = in + v + other }
scala> (MethCall(1) -> "input: ")(" ,other")
res1: String = input: 1 ,other
```

2) It could also be an implicit conversion from `Tuple2` to a `Function1` which uses `apply`/`()` method on it:

```
implicit def tuple2toFunct1[A, B, C](t: Tuple2[A, B]) = (v: C) => identity(v)
scala> (1 -> 2)("three")
res1: String = three
```

To be sure you can inspect the type of the expression in the IDE/REPL.